# WPF Binding not updating with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a TabControl in which I set the DataContext to an instance of the [this](http://pastebin.com/puKhVSs6) class, It's basicly a wrapper for DependencyProperties of a static class with the same properties.

In my Markup I set the DataContext like this

```
<TabControl DataContext="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=Settings}">
```

and binding to the property within the TabControl like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Url, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

However, this does not lead to any updates of the source when the content of the TextBox is changed. I can change the content of the TextBox, let it loose focus etc. it does just not update the source.

Comment: Check output window. Do you see any binding errors over there?

Comment: No, there are no binding-errors in the output window

Answer (score 0):

Url is a dependency property and ***when set from XAML, wrapper property setter won't be called***.

From [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx):

> The current WPF implementation of its XAML processor is inherently
>   dependency property aware. The WPF XAML processor uses property system
>   methods for dependency properties when loading binary XAML and
>   processing attributes that are dependency properties. This effectively
>   bypasses the property wrappers. When you implement custom dependency
>   properties, you must account for this behavior and should avoid
>   placing any other code in your property wrapper other than the
>   property system methods GetValue and SetValue.

---

In case you want to do something on its property changed you should provide **`PropertyChangedCallback`** and write code there.

You can refer to the sample [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) in case PropertyChangedCallback is new to you. Something like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UrlProperty = 
  DependencyProperty.Register(
  "Url",
  typeof(string),
  typeof(SettingsWrapper),
  new PropertyMetadata(OnUrlChanged)
  )
);

private static void OnUrlChanged(DependencyObject d,
                                 DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SettingsWrapper instance = (SettingsWrapper)d;
    instance.Settings.Url = e.NewValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I tried it, but sadly it doesn't change anything on the behavior =/

Comment: Does `OnUrlChanged` get hit on property change?

Answer (score 0):

You said in a (now deleted) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314399/wpf-binding-not-updating-with-updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged#comment39459031_25314556) that your `Window` has `x:Name="self"`, however the `Window` class does not have a property called `Settings`.

If this is an attached property, you need to reference it by the attached property by the full name, and wrap it in parenthesis.

For example,

```
<TabControl DataContext="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=(local:MyClass.Settings)}">
```

See [WPF Attached Property Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5832208/302677) for more info.

Comment: I also said that I have a property Settings within my Window-Code

Comment: @skeleten The `<Window>` class does not have a property called `Settings`, so WPF will not be able to resolve the binding. If it is an attached property, you have to use the correct attached property syntax for binding purposes. You could also try setting the Window.DataContext to the Window object itself (`this.DataContext = this` in the constructor), and binding to `DataContext.Settings`, and that should work.