# Set the ContentPresenter's content color, when the content is not a text

Tags: wpf, xaml, contentcontrol, contentpresenter

Let's say that My `ContentPresenter` contains a `Viewbox` with `Path`s inside instead of some text, how do I change the Color of those `Path`s from the `Content Presenter`

**Example**

I have this `ResourceDictionary` :

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
            <Viewbox>
              <Grid>
                <Grid Name="backgroundGrid" Width="48" Height="48" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <Path Data="M19.833,0L32.5,0 32.5,19.833999 52.334,19.833999 52.334,32.500999 32.5,32.500999 32.5,52.333 19.833,52.333 19.833,32.500999 0,32.500999 0,19.833999 19.833,19.833999z" 
Stretch="Uniform" 
Fill="?????" 
Width="26" Height="26" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                  <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                      <TransformGroup.Children>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                      </TransformGroup.Children>
                    </TransformGroup>
                  </Path.RenderTransform>
                </Path>
              </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

and I have the `ContentPresenter` in a `ControlTemplate` of let's say a `Button`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IconButton}">
       <Border>
          <Grid>                            
              <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenterIcon" ContentSource="Icon"/>                        
          </Grid>
       </Border>
...
```

Assigning `Icon` to the `ContentSource` property just means that the ContentPresenter is having that Viewbox as a content.

What should I put in the Fill property of the Path Element, and which property should I change in the ContentPresenter to make its value propagate to the Fill property ?

Hope I was clear.

**Update :**

I desperately tried to set the ContentPresenter's TextElement.Foreground property and "Relativesource" bind the Path's Fill property to it, but that predictably didn't work.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
                <Viewbox>
                  <Grid>
                    <Grid Name="backgroundGrid" Width="48" Height="48" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Path Data="M19.833,0L32.5,0 32.5,19.833999 52.334,19.833999 52.334,32.500999 32.5,32.500999 32.5,52.333 19.833,52.333 19.833,32.500999 0,32.500999 0,19.833999 19.833,19.833999z" 
    Stretch="Uniform" 
    Fill="{Binding Path=TextElement.Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" 
    Width="26" Height="26" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                      <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                          <TransformGroup.Children>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                          </TransformGroup.Children>
                        </TransformGroup>
                      </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                  </Grid>
                </Viewbox>
```

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IconButton}">
           <Border>
              <Grid>                            
                  <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenterIcon" TextElement.Foreground="Red" ContentSource="Icon"/>                        
              </Grid>
           </Border>
    ...
```

Comment: Please define _"didn't work"_. What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second attempt should have worked. The reason it didn't is because you are binding to an **[Attached Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**.

Attached property binding requires special syntax. The output window in visual studio probably tells you that the path could not be found. This should work:

```
Fill="{Binding Path=(TextElement.Foreground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}"
```

The only change is the parenthesis around the `Path` string. For more information, see [WPF Attached Property Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832208/wpf-attached-property-data-binding).

Comment: Mother of Parenthesis !! I ignored all about them !