# Setting DockPanel.Dock according to DependencyProperty of a custom control does not work

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an enum:

```cs
public enum ImageTextLocation 
{ 
   Left, 
   Top, 
   Right, 
   Bottom 
}
```

And a custom `UserControl` that contains dependency property of that enum.

```xml
<Button Content="{Binding ButtonText}"
        Command="{Binding Command}"
        Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border x:Name="border"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="{Binding Path=TextLocation, Converter={StaticResource EnumToDockConvert}}" 
                                      Margin="2,6,0,2"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

```
public partial class ImageButtonControl : UserControl
{ 
    public ImageTextLocation TextLocation
    {
        get => (ImageTextLocation)GetValue(TextLocationProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextLocationProperty, value); 
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextLocationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "TextLocation", 
            typeof(ImageTextLocation), 
            typeof(ImageButtonControl), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ImageTextLocation.Left, 
                PropertyChangedCallback) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true, }
        );
    
    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var imageButton = (ImageButtonControl)d;
        var newLocation = (ImageTextLocation)e.NewValue;
        switch (newLocation)
        {
            case ImageTextLocation.Left: 
                 imageButton.SetCurrentValue(TextLocationProperty, ImageTextLocation.Left);
                 break;
            case ImageTextLocation.Right:
                 imageButton.SetCurrentValue(TextLocationProperty, ImageTextLocation.Right);
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added created a converter that converts from `ImageTextLocation` to `Dock`:

```cs
public class EnumToDockConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, 
                          Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, 
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value == null)
           return Dock.Left;
    
        ImageTextLocation location = (ImageTextLocation)value;
        var dock = Enum.Parse(typeof(Dock), location.ToString());
        return dock;
    }
    
    public object ConvertBack(object value, 
                              Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, 
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And added an instance of the converter to the resources of my `UserControl`:

```xml
<coverter:EnumToDockConverter x:Key="EnumToDockConvert"/>
```

Then, I try to set the `DockPanel.Dock` of the custom control using `TextLocation="{Binding ImageTextPosition}"`, where `ImageTextPosition` is the string property of my view model bound to the `UserControl`.

```xml
<controls:ImageButtonControl TextLocation="{Binding ImageTextPosition}"/>
```

DockPanel's Dock does not set when I set the dependency property.

Comment: DockPanel.Dock is an attached property, you can't bind it this way. Instead, call GetDock and SetDock when your TextLocation property changes and you can convert from your enum to the dock layout there. Or use the attached property syntax described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832208/wpf-attached-property-data-binding

Comment: Thanks @John V, Can you give an example of code?

Comment: Note that your PropertyChangedCallback is redundant. It makes no sense to call `imageButton.SetCurrentValue` with the value that the property already has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any need to use a converter. In your property changed callback, call `DockPanel.SetDock()` directly to change the dock position of the content presenter. I would also define `ImageTextLocation` in terms of `Dock` so that you can cast it.

UPDATE: OP clarified that `ImageButtonControl` overrides the default `ControlTemplate` of the `Button`, so I have updated my answer to work in that scenario. Derive directly from `Button`, instead of `UserControl`, so the contents of the template are accessible without jumping through hoops.

ImageButton.xaml

```xml
<!-- bound the content of the Button to TextLocation for testing -->
<Button x:Class="TestApp.ImageButton"
        Content="{Binding TextLocation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
        Command="{Binding Command}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                      Margin="2,6,0,2" 
                                      DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>

                    <!-- Put something the DockPanel for the content 
                         presenter to dock relative to. Presumably this 
                         would be an image -->
                    <Button Content="Main Content"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Code Behind

```cs
public enum ImageTextLocation 
{ 
    Left = (int)Dock.Left,
    Top = (int)Dock.Top,
    Right = (int)Dock.Right,
    Bottom = (int)Dock.Bottom
}

public partial class ImageButton : Button
{
    private ContentPresenter _contentPresenter;

    public ImageButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ImageTextLocation TextLocation
    {
        get => (ImageTextLocation)GetValue(TextLocationProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextLocationProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextLocationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(TextLocation),
            typeof(ImageTextLocation),
            typeof(ImageButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((d, e) => ((ImageButton)d).SetDock((Dock)e.NewValue)));

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _contentPresenter = (ContentPresenter)GetTemplateChild("contentPresenter");
        SetDock((Dock)TextLocation);
    }

    public void SetDock(Dock newLocation)
    {
        if (_contentPresenter == null) return; //template not yet applied
        DockPanel.SetDock(_contentPresenter, newLocation);
    }
}
```

Demo:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow">
    <UniformGrid>
        <local:ImageButton TextLocation="Left"  />
        <local:ImageButton TextLocation="Right" />
        <local:ImageButton TextLocation="Top"   />
        <local:ImageButton TextLocation="Bottom"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, My ContentPresenter is inside a button template. So I cannot get the presenter like this imageButton.contentPresenter. I have edited my question

Comment: The purpose to add contentpresenter inside button template is to set text of a button with an image. And dockpanel is needed for contentpresenter so that text of button can be docked dynamically

Comment: Thanks it works, please change <local:ImageButtonControl TextLocation="Left"  /> to <local:ImageButton TextLocation="Left"  /> because in your case the class name is ImageButton

Comment: Okay, but delete all these comments.