# Attached property in DataGridColumnHeader template not updating

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, attached-properties, datagridcolumnheader

**What is my goal:**

I want to create a custom template for a column header in DataGrid - DataGridColumnHeader. This template is supposed to fetch data from the attached property (in a real program, these will be properties such as: indicator whether the column is filtered, column title rotation angle, and so on)

Since DataGrid columns don't inherit DataContext I use method with BindingProxy class (description here: https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

Everything looks OK, but something is not right - if I use the attachet property in the DataGridColumnHeader template, notifications about changing this property do not work.

In the example below, I have bound the same property in different ways and everything works except for the DataGridColumnHeader template.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

[image: MyApp]

**Reploduce problem:**

The project is written in .Net Framework 4.7.1
To reproduce the problem, please create a new WPF project named "MyApp" for .Net Framework and add the following files to it:

File: **MainWindow.xaml** - window definition

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="950">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!--Proxy to "transfer" DataContext to -->
            <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" MyData="{Binding}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    
    
    <StackPanel Margin="10">

        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SomeIndicator}" Content="- regular binding (without proxy object) - it works"/>
        
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyData.SomeIndicator, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" Content="- binding via proxy object - it works"/>
        
        <CheckBox local:AttProp.MyAttProp="{Binding MyData.SomeIndicator, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
                  Style="{StaticResource SimpleCheckBoxStyle}"/>


        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,20,0,20">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyData.SomeIndicator, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
                                  Content="- binding via proxy object (DataGrid header) - it works"/>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"
                                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource SimpleHeaderStyle}"
                                    local:AttProp.MyAttProp="{Binding MyData.SomeIndicator, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Label Content="Use this button, please ===>" Foreground="Red"/>
            <Button Content="Toggle False/True" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}" Height="30" Width="150"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

File **Styles.xaml** - extremely simplified styles

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp">

    
    <!--Custom style for DataGridColumnHeader-->
    <Style x:Key="SimpleHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{TemplateBinding local:AttProp.MyAttProp}" Foreground="Red"
                              Content="- binding via attached property, proxy object and custom DataGridColumnHeader style - it doesn't work :( "
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <!--Custom style for CheckBox-->
    <Style x:Key="SimpleCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{TemplateBinding local:AttProp.MyAttProp }"
                              Content="- binding via attached property, proxy object and custom CheckBox style - it works"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

File **AttProp.cs** - definition my attached property

```csharp
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class AttProp
    {
        //Create attached property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyAttPropProperty
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyAttProp", typeof(bool), typeof(AttProp), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

        public static void SetMyAttProp(DependencyObject target, bool value)=>target.SetValue(MyAttPropProperty, value);
        public static bool GetMyAttProp(DependencyObject target) => (bool)target.GetValue(MyAttPropProperty);

    }
}
```

File **BindingProxy.cs** - definition of proxy class

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class BindingProxy : Freezable
    {
        #region Overrides of Freezable

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new BindingProxy();
        }

        #endregion

        public object MyData
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(MyDataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyDataProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyData", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

File **ViewModel.cs** - view model :)

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class ViewModel : ICommand, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Properties
        private bool _someIndicator = false;
        public bool SomeIndicator
        {
            get => _someIndicator;
            set
            {
                _someIndicator = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public List<string> SomeData { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD" };

        public ICommand ButtonClick { get; set; }
        #endregion


        #region Constructor
        public ViewModel() => ButtonClick = this;
        #endregion


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        #endregion


        #region ICommand interface implementation
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
        public void Execute(object parameter) => SomeIndicator =! SomeIndicator;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I tried various ways of binding data in the template, but none of them brought the expected effect - changing the property does not affect the change of the checkbox in the header of the column to which the template is applied.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Attached Property Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832208/wpf-attached-property-data-binding)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the solution in the thread you referenced doesn't work for me. I read this before writing the question on SO, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the attached property of the column itself but you bind to the `DataGridColumnHeader` in your `Style`.

This should work:

```
<Style x:Key="SimpleHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Column.(local:AttProp.MyAttProp), 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader}}" Foreground="Red"
                              Content="- binding via attached property, proxy object and custom DataGridColumnHeader style - it doesn't work :( "
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. that's exactly what I needed. I didn't know I was binding to the wrong place, in fact I didn't know exactly where I was binding. Thanks to you everything is clear. Thank you again.