# Multibinding to an attached property

Tags: wpf

I have a situation where I'm trying to Multibind to a converter to change my foreground color based on an attached property. Specifically, the Selector.IsSelectionActive attached property.

Following the advice in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832208/wpf-attached-property-data-binding) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309008/binding-converterparameter) and this [blog](http://www.shujaat.net/2011/02/wpf-binding-converter-parameter.html) I've managed to get something together that almost works, but the critical piece (the attached property) doesn't get passed through correctly.

Here's what I have so far:

```xml
            <Label x:Name="Fish"  Style="{DynamicResource ItemLabel}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Template="{DynamicResource moduleItem}" >
                <Label.Foreground>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisplayStatusConv}">
                        <Binding Path="DisplayStatus"/>
                        <Binding Path="(Selector.IsSelectionActive)" 
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Label}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Foreground>
```

But the second value I get passed is just a DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

Comment: linked questions use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`. but most likely Label doesn't set that Selector.IsSelectionActive property

Comment: That worked!  I could swear I tried that at one point.  I was thinking that if I used Self, it would try to look at the binding rather than the label, and I can confirm via Snoop that the property is indeed on the label.  Does find ancestor stop at the first label it encounters?

Comment: Note that *binding* a Label to a string results in very bad performance (unless the Binding.Mode is OneTime). Better use the highly optimized TextBlock to display a short text.

Comment: @BionicCode Thank you, good to know.  In this case, the label consists of an image, a TextBlock, and another image.  Would I be better off using a different container?