# WPF XAML StringFormat assign amount of decimal places through binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have the need to give the user the ability to set their own Decimal Formating option in XAML.

I know how to set StringFormat into Binding, but I only know how to do it manually. How can I Bind the String Format value inside a binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I Bind the String Format value inside a binding.

You *cannot* because `StringFormat` is not a dependency property.

But you could use a multi binding that binds to two properties, the actual source property and the format source property, and an `IMultiValueConverter` class:

[WPF Binding and Dynamically Assigning StringFormat Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099048/wpf-binding-and-dynamically-assigning-stringformat-property)

**WPF: MultiBinding and IMultiValueConverter:** https://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use ContentStringFormat property.

URL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx

Use it like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyFormat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Label Content="{Binding ValueToFormat}"
       ContentStringFormat="{Binding MyFormat}" />
```

Comment: I am trying to use it for DataGrid Cell. Which does not have ContentStringFormat property. Only Labels do I belive.

Comment: If that's the case, you can just do the formatting in the `ViewModel`, manually. Or, you can use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, and put a `TextBox` under the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`.